# How to grab all the page urls through website url?

Tags: php

PHP: How to get all the page links through website url (something like sitemap result) ?

Am looking to obtain all links array in result.

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: Need all the links in php

Comment: what kind of file you have ?

Comment: A simple form with one input field for site url. On form submission i want to show all the links within that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
        <?php
    /**
     * Base crawler class
     */
    class CrawlerBase {

       /**
        * remove specified $tag form $content
        */
       private function removeTag($tag, $content) {
          //$pat = '/<'.$tag.'.*>.*<\/'.$tag.'>/s';
          $pat = '@<'.$tag.'[^>]*?.*?</'.$tag.'>@siu';
          return preg_replace($pat, '',  $content);
       }

       /**
        * remove unwanted tags from content
        */
       public function cleanContent($content) {

          $content = $this->removeTag('script', $content);
          $content = $this->removeTag('css', $content);
          $content = $this->removeTag('object', $content);
          return $content;
       }

    }

    /**
     * Read html page content
     */
    class HtmlReader extends CrawlerBase{

       public function getPageContent($url) {
          return file_get_contents($url);
       }
    }

    /**
     * class for html document
     */
    class HtmlDocument extends CrawlerBase {
       /**
        * Document content
        */
       private  $content;

       public function __construct($content) {
          $this->content = $content;
       }

       public function getBody() {
          return new HtmlDocumentBody($this->content);
       }

       public function getHead() {
          return new HtmlDocumentHead($this->content);
       }

    }

    /**
     * html Head section class
     */
    class HtmlDocumentHead extends CrawlerBase {

       /**
        * Document content
        */
       private  $content;

       public function __construct($htmlContent = null) {
          if(!empty($htmlContent)) {
             $this->findDocumentHead($htmlContent);
          }
       }

       /**
        * find document <head> part
        */
       public function findDocumentHead($htmlContent) {
          $matches = array();
          preg_match('/(<head>)(.*)(<\/head>)/si', $htmlContent, $matches);
          $this->content =  $matches[2];
       }

    }

    /**
     * html body section class
     */
    class HtmlDocumentBody extends CrawlerBase  {

       /**
        * Document content
        */
       private $content;

       public function __construct($htmlContent = null) {
          $this->findDocumentBody($htmlContent);
       }

       /**
        * read links from content
        */
       public function grabLinks() {

          $links = array();
          $matches = array();
          $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
          preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $this->content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
          if(!empty($matches)) {
             foreach ($matches as $link) {
                $links[] = new ContentLink($link);
             }
          }
          return   $links;
       }

       /**
        * find document <body> part
        */
       public function findDocumentBody($content) {
          $matches = array();
          preg_match('/(<body>)(.*)(<\/body>)/is', $content, $matches);
          $this->content =  $matches[2];
       }

       public function getDocumentBody() {
          return $this->content;
       }

       public function getStrippedBody() {
          return new StrippedBody($this->content);
       }

    }

    /**
     * cleaned body (with no tags)
     */
    class StrippedBody extends CrawlerBase {

       /**
        * Document content
        */
       private  $content;

       public function __construct($UnsrtippedBodyContent = null) {
          if(!empty($UnsrtippedBodyContent)) {
             $UnsrtippedBodyContent = $this->cleanContent($UnsrtippedBodyContent);

             $this->content = strip_tags($UnsrtippedBodyContent);
          }
       }

       public function getContent() {
          return $this->content;
       }
    }

    /**
     * link class
     */
    class ContentLink extends CrawlerBase {
       /**
        * Document content
        */
       public $fullUrl;
       public $url;
       public $anchor;
       public $type;

       public function __construct(array $linkData) {
          $this->parseLinkData($linkData);
       }

       public function parseLinkData(array $linkData) {
          $this->fullUrl = $linkData[0];
          $this->url = $linkData[2];
          $this->anchor = strip_tags($linkData[3]);
          if(preg_match('/^http/', $linkData[2])) {
             $this->type = 2; //external
          } else {
             $this->type = 1; //local
          }
       }
    }

    /**
     * body words class. find, count, append
     */
    class BodyWords extends CrawlerBase {

       /**
        * Document content
        */
       private $words = array();

       public function __construct() {

       }

       private function countWords($uncountedWordsArray) {
          $wordsArray = array_count_values($uncountedWordsArray);
          $this->removeShortWords($wordsArray);
          asort($wordsArray);
          return $wordsArray;
       }

       private function removeShortWords(&$countedWordsArray) {
          if(!empty($countedWordsArray)) {
             foreach($countedWordsArray as $word => $count) {
                if(strlen($word) < 4) {
                   unset($countedWordsArray[$word]);
                }
             }
          }
       }

       public function findWords($cleanBodyText) {
          $uncountedWordsArray = preg_split("/[\s,.?!]+/", $cleanBodyText);
          return $this->countWords($uncountedWordsArray);
       }

       public function appendWords($wordsArray, $page='/') {
          if(!empty($wordsArray)) {
             foreach ($wordsArray as $word => $count) {
                if(array_key_exists($word, $this->words)) {
                   $this->words[$page][$word] = $this->words[$page][$word] + $count;
                } else {
                   $this->words[$page][$word] = $count;
                }
             }
          }
       }

       public function getWords() {
          return $this->words;
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can use `DOMDocument` and `XPATH` for parsing :)

Comment: Is that recursively working?

Comment: you should at least provide an example of usage, instead of copy/paste some class